# react quill img width

Tags: reactjs, image-resizing, quill, react-quill

```
     <ReactQuill
          theme={'snow'}
          modules={modules}
          value={"<p><img src="aa.png" alt="dd" width="100"></p>"}
          formats={formats}
          onChange={onContentsChange}
        />
```

In this case, "alt" and "width" are ignored but only "src" is applied.

What's the reason for this?

solution of react quill issue